# i have a very messy situation with grub lost and a potentially corrupt partiton

Tags: fedora, btrfs, chroot

SO, we start off with, [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/12qju32/comment/jivky0) after that i understood that the issue was arising because i was using btrfs and root00 and home were subvolumes.

However, before i understood this, i tried to copy all the files from root00 to the plain directory, /dev/nvme1n1p3, the copying didn't go about well [SHOCKER /s] and i knew this wasnt a good idea but i wasnt sure why, so i took a clonezilla backup. I have now restored it of course but when im trying to chroot into it it doesn't work, im getting:
`chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Input/output error`

now when looking up this error, i came across a forum post suggesting the dependencies haven't been met for bash.

and for some reason i found myself running: `ls -a /mnt/bin/ | grep "bash"` i get:
https://pastebin.com/m3HrbYXh

my deduction was that all of these packages have been somehow corrupted, now i have no clue what the next step is to solving this, all i want to do is to chroot in to fix grub now that i know how to mount a btrfs subvolume.